# Operations with text and delimiters

Tags: c, text

The task is: to read the text from file and to read an array of delimiters from keyboard. Than the program should search the sequence of delimiters in the text and, if it would be found 3 times or more, swap all the odd strings in a circle. Also it should detete all the words, which exceed the length limit, entered by user, but only in odd strings.
This is what i've got now:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); //entering the text
    const int numberOfCharactersToRead = 128;
    char* inputText = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char) * numberOfCharactersToRead));
    FILE *fp;
    fopen_s(&fp, "D:\texxxt.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("nFile not foundn");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    fgets(inputText, numberOfCharactersToRead, fp);
    printf("Enter the sequence of delimiters: "); //entering delimiters
    const int numberOfDelimitersToRead = 6;
    char* delimiters = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char) * numberOfDelimitersToRead));
    int indexer = 0;
    for (indexer = 0; indexer < numberOfDelimitersToRead; indexer++)
    {
        delimiters[indexer] = getchar();
    }
    //Trying to use strtok in order to devide text into rows (unsuccesful)
    char delims[] = "/n";
    char *pch = strtok_s(NULL, inputText, &delims);
    printf("nLexems:");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf("n%s", pch);
        pch = strtok_s(NULL, inputText, &delims);
    }
    return 0;
}

int symcount(void) 
{ //function searching the quantity of delimiters
    char str[20], ch;
    int count = 0, i;
    printf("nEnter a string : ");
    scanf_s("%s", &str);
    printf("nEnter the character to be searched : ");
    scanf_s("%c", &ch);
    for (i = 0; str[i] != ''; i++) 
    {
        if (str[i] == ch)
            count++;
    }
    if (count == 0)
        printf("nCharacter '%c'is not present", ch);
    else
        printf("nOccurence of character '%c' : %d", ch, count);
    return (0);
}
```

I dont really know how to devide the text into rows and how to make my program differentiate even and odd strings. I'm really confused

Comment: First delimit your  *code* properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of [`strtok_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx) is the following:

> char *strtok_s(char *strToken, const char *strDelimit, char **context);

You are mixing up the parameters. The 1st parameter should be a pointer to the input string and the 2nd parameter should be the delimiter string. Finally after the function is executed the 3rd parameter will be passed a pointer to the string after the position where the delimiter was found, or `NULL` if no delimiter was found. This pointer can then be passed onto the next `strtok_s` call to continue the search.

```
char *pchNext;
char *pch = strtok_s(inputText, delimiters, &pchNext);

while (pch != NULL)
{
    printf("\n%s", pch);
    pch = strtok_s(NULL, delimiters, &pchNext); // The first parameter can be NULL here
}
```

Also, the textual representation of the newline character is `\n`, not `/n` or `n`.